# why does it in texture paint mode paint on each face at the same time?

Tags: texture-painting

When I texture paint somewhere, it copies itself on each other face of my mesh too. How can I disable this? I don't know why that happens, it didn't earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out, that I had my UV map scaled way too much. It didn't paint on faces, but only replicated itself to fit the UV.